# Adding individual elements within a tuple Erlang

Tags: tuples, erlang

I want to know how to add individual elements within a Tuple.
For example If I have two tuples:

```
A={1,2,3} and B={4,5,6}
```

The result I want is to add the corresponding elements of each tuple(1+4,2+5,3+6) so the output I would get is

```
A+B={5,7,9}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that both tuples have the same size, the easiest way to do this is to turn the tuples into lists, iterate over them and then create a tuple again, like:

```erlang
list_to_tuple([Ai + Bi || {Ai, Bi} <- lists:zip(tuple_to_list(A), tuple_to_list(B))]).
```

or, if you want to iterate over the tuples:

```erlang
sum_tuples(A, B) ->
    list_to_tuple(sum_tuples_iterate(A, B, 1, [])).

sum_tuples_iterate(A, _B, I, Acc) when I > tuple_size(A) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc);
sum_tuples_iterate(A, B, I, Acc) ->
    sum_tuples_iterate(A, B, I+1, [element(I, A) + element(I, B) | Acc]).
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is:

```
> {X,Y,Z}={1,2,3}.
{1,2,3}
> {A,B,C}={5,6,7}.
{5,6,7}
> {X+A,Y+B,Z+C}.
{6,8,10}
```

This makes use of the fact that tuples should be finite

Answer (score 0):

We can encapsulate this logic in a simple function using pattern matching:

```
sum_tuples({A, B, C}, {X, Y, Z}) -> {A + X, B + Y, C + Z}.
```